# How to get AJAX response authorization header

Tags: jquery, ajax

In one of my code I've the following jQuery AJAX call

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://api.myapi.com/v1/post/",
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    data: JSON.stringify(body),
    success: function (data, status, xhr)
    {
        console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders()); // Output-01
        console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Authorization')); // Output-02
    },
    error: function (data) {
        //console.log(data);
    }
})
```

I have got the following output:

- Output-01: 
  `content-type: application/json`
- Output-02: 
  `null`

I can't figure out what did I do wrong?

Comment: Try checking your browsers developer console `<F12>` to ensure the header is being returned as you expect.

Comment: An `Authorization` header in the *response*? Are you sure that's correct. The norm, by far, is to only send the Auth headers in the request in order to identify exactly *who* is requesting the resource.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan yes, that's correct.

Comment: If it's your API then you're defining what's sent back. As Rory said, however, it'd be an odd thing to send that *back*, e.g., https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Authorization You only have access to the headers actually sent.

Comment: @War10ck I see my Network tab is showing all the available headers like `content-type`, `authorization`, `statusCode` and so on.

Comment: `Authorization` != `authorization`, and it may also be affected by any jQuery default ajax handling in play or whatever else jQuery may do to XHR requests.

Comment: @Taplar `authorization` is also not worked. You see my `console.log(xhr.getAllResponseHeaders());` returns only `content-type: application/json` and there is no other header is accessible from my JS code :(

Comment: @Taplar you are absolutely right. I am performing a cross site request. and your suggestion works perfect.

Comment: Alright, then I'll vote to close as a duplicate.  Glad you got it figured out though.